# Magento email goes to spam or junk mail

Tags: magento, email, magento-1.7

I setting email code in over module in magento. The code is work fine but when i check email they are found in Spam or junk mail. My question is how to prevent this email where they dose not goes to junk or Spam box. thanks in advance

Comment: Did you use Mage::getModel('core/email') for sending emails or are you using a PHP patch (mail() function) ?

Comment: yes i am using this Mage::getModel('core/email')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most probably due to settings of your domain and what reputation it has, not anything to do with Magento.

See this : https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en-uk&hlrm=en
And check if there are any other problems, which might lead to low domain reputation.

But considering the code and mail content in particular, try following these guidelines : 
http://www.activecampaign.com/help/improving-delivery/

Comment: Two things about Magento 1) If it reads like junk mail, it ends up in junk mail. Change titles and content in the template to be non-spammy. 2) If you're not sending through an Email Service Provider and using the built-in dump to the local MX that Magento ships with, you're pretty much considered a spammer in today's world. Real Email Servers require a login, transmit email using SSL/TLS security, have SPF records and Reverse Pointer Records set up in DNS.

Comment: the first link pertains to gsuite users

Answer (score 8):

Changing

```
System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings > Set Return-Path to YES
```

Fixed it for me. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

After all the possible solution you have done and still not get mail in Inbox then contact to your server people and tell him to restart the server once.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have relevant SPF and DKIM records for your web server's IP in the DNS settings for your domain. It may be that your web server is not listed as an authorised sender of email for your domain.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with Magento email delivery when I first started hosting Magento. I've always used Postfix and after setting spf, dkim, etc. I was able to get a score of 9/10 however, most my hotmail customers still see emails in junk folder. The pressure from clients was enormous especially when they hear the word 'junk', no matter how much you explain to them (such as domain reputation).

Anyway I had to hang it up because at that stage that was all I could do. Recently I started to use GC and because GC blocks port 25 for outgoing, I cannot even get Postfix working at all. So I had to configure Postfix using G Suit SMTP relay and suprising it worked really well, even with Microsoft emails (land in inbox rather than junk folder).

So for all you guys struggling with Magento email deliverbility out there, you should give this approach a go. If you don't like messing around with server, you can use third party SMTP such as SendGrid which I also had good success with. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Update the DNS records with DKIM and SFP. This worked for me. My contact us mails were getting sent into the spam folder.